# OUTLOOK_定期開催予定の変更を取得する方法

Tags: c#

お世話になります。
C#でOUTLOOKの予定表を取得、表示させようとしています。
Filterで対象日に絞りこんだ際、定期開催の会議で
　・元の開催期間が対象日外
　　　4/1～4/30　まで　毎日開催

・定期開催の１会議を対象日に移動
　　　4/30の会議を順延して5/2にする

・Filterを5/2で設定

の条件にした際に、データが引っかからなくて困っています。

Filterの対象を広げるだけでは、問題の解決になってないので
なんとか方法がないかと調べていますが、見つからず。

何か対応方法などあればご教示頂きたく、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 取得したいのは「予定」と「変更のあった予定」どちらでしょうか。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。変更のあった予定です。